# How can I change numpy array structure?

Tags: arrays, numpy, structure, reshape

How can I change numpy array structure?
I want to change as below.

```
(1,3,2) --> (1,2,3)
```

from
`[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]`

to `[[1,3,5],[2,4,6]]`

Thanks.

Comment: `a.transpose(0, 2, 1)`? or `a.swapaxes(1, 2)`.  Have you tried anything?  Your provided shapes also don't match the arrays you have posted.

Answer (score -1):

A well known 'list' transpose, applied to your example:

```
In [14]: alist = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
In [15]: alist
Out[15]: [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
In [16]: blist = list(zip(*alist))
In [17]: blist
Out[17]: [(1, 3, 5), (2, 4, 6)]
```

Applying numpy's transpose:

```
In [18]: np.transpose(alist)
Out[18]: 
array([[1, 3, 5],
       [2, 4, 6]])
```